# TypeError: SnakeGame is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a snake command for my discord bot, taking spunot from a code I found online but can't implement it in mine! in the console log the error is this:

`TypeError: SnakeGame is not a constructor`

while the code is this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

...

//snake (Work in progress)
    const snakeGame = new SnakeGame(client);

    const WIDTH = 15;
    const HEIGHT = 10;
    const gameBoard = [];
    const apple = { x: 1, y: 1 };

    var SnakeGame = class SnakeGame {
        constructor() {
            this.snake = [{ x: 5, y: 5 }];
            this.snakeLength = 1;
            this.score = 0;
            this.gameEmbed = null;
            this.inGame = false;
            for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                for (let x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                    gameBoard[y * WIDTH + x] = "";
                }
            }
        }

        gameBoardToString() {
            let str = ""
            for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                for (let x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                    if (x == apple.x && y == apple.y) {
                        str += "";
                        continue;
                    }

                    let flag = true;
                    for (let s = 0; s < this.snake.length; s++) {
                        if (x == this.snake[s].x && y == this.snake[s].y) {
                            str += "";
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (flag)
                        str += gameBoard[y * WIDTH + x];
                }
                str += "\n";
            }
            return str;
        }

        isLocInSnake(pos) {
            return this.snake.find(sPos => sPos.x == pos.x && sPos.y == pos.y);
        };

        newAppleLoc() {
            let newApplePos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
            do {
                newApplePos = { x: parseInt(Math.random() * WIDTH), y: parseInt(Math.random() * HEIGHT) };
            } while (this.isLocInSnake(newApplePos))

            apple.x = newApplePos.x;
            apple.y = newApplePos.y;
        }

        newGame(msg) {
            if (this.inGame)
                return;

            this.inGame = true;
            this.score = 0;
            this.snakeLength = 1;
            this.snake = [{ x: 5, y: 5 }];
            this.newAppleLoc();
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#03ad03')
                .setTitle('Snake Game')
                .setDescription(this.gameBoardToString())
                .setTimestamp();

            msg.channel.send(embed).then(emsg => {
                this.gameEmbed = emsg;
                this.gameEmbed.react('⬅️');
                this.gameEmbed.react('⬆️');
                this.gameEmbed.react('⬇️');
                this.gameEmbed.react('➡️');

                this.waitForReaction();
            });
        }

        step() {
            if (apple.x == this.snake[0].x && apple.y == this.snake[0].y) {
                this.score += 1;
                this.snakeLength++;
                this.newAppleLoc();
            }

            const editEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#03ad03')
                .setTitle('Snake Game')
                .setDescription(this.gameBoardToString())
                .setTimestamp();
            this.gameEmbed.edit(editEmbed);

            this.waitForReaction();
        }

        gameOver() {
            this.inGame = false;
            const editEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#03ad03')
                .setTitle('Snake Game')
                .setDescription("GAME OVER!\nSCORE: " + this.score)
                .setTimestamp();
            this.gameEmbed.edit(editEmbed);

            this.gameEmbed.reactions.removeAll()
        }

        filter(reaction, user) {
            return ['⬅️', '⬆️', '⬇️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id !== this.gameEmbed.author.id;
        }

        waitForReaction() {
            this.gameEmbed.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => this.filter(reaction, user), { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    const snakeHead = this.snake[0];
                    const nextPos = { x: snakeHead.x, y: snakeHead.y };
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️') {
                        let nextX = snakeHead.x - 1;
                        if (nextX < 0)
                            nextX = WIDTH - 1;
                        nextPos.x = nextX;
                    }
                    else if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬆️') {
                        let nextY = snakeHead.y - 1;
                        if (nextY < 0)
                            nextY = HEIGHT - 1;
                        nextPos.y = nextY;
                    }
                    else if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬇️') {
                        let nextY = snakeHead.y + 1;
                        if (nextY >= HEIGHT)
                            nextY = 0;
                        nextPos.y = nextY;
                    }
                    else if (reaction.emoji.name === '➡️') {
                        let nextX = snakeHead.x + 1;
                        if (nextX >= WIDTH)
                            nextX = 0;
                        nextPos.x = nextX;
                    }

                    reaction.users.remove(reaction.users.cache.filter(user => user.id !== this.gameEmbed.author.id).first().id).then(() => {
                        if (this.isLocInSnake(nextPos)) {
                            this.gameOver();
                        }
                        else {
                            this.snake.unshift(nextPos);
                            if (this.snake.length > this.snakeLength)
                                this.snake.pop();

                            this.step();
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    this.gameOver();
                });
        }
    }
    
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'snake')) {
        snakeGame.newGame(msg);
    }
```

I tried to add var and const everywhere but it doesn't still not working :((
The "..." are others commands so nvm.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the SnakeGame class in the first line, but the class is defined few lines below.
You need to make sure that the class is first defined and then used:

```js
const WIDTH = 15;
const HEIGHT = 10;
const gameBoard = [];
const apple = { x: 1, y: 1 };

//original code: var SnakeGame = class SnakeGame - assigning class to a variable with the same name is pointless, so just define the class
class SnakeGame {// that entire code for the class...}

// creating class instance after the class has been defined
const snakeGame = new SnakeGame(client);
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
2021-01-17T11:11:28.024548+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at SnakeGame.newGame (/app/index.js:1055:25)
2021-01-17T11:11:28.024549+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:1153:19)
2021-01-17T11:11:28.024550+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)```

now the error message is this :((
The error line of the code is the NewGame line if it can help you.